# Architecturing method inheritance / hiding method in child class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to write some Deterministic Finite Automaton related algorithms. So the obvious start is to define the entities: `DFA`, `State` and `Edges`. However, I though since the `DFA` is a kind of graph I should have basic classes `Graph`, `Node` and `Edge` each implementing `IGraph`, `INode` and `IEdge`. And then have `DFA` and `State` extend `Graph` and `Node`.

So the stripped down code of `Graph` is:

```
class Graph
{
    //...
    public void addNode(INode node)
    {
        //...
    }
    //... 
}
```

Now the main difference between `State` and `Node` is that `State` adds properties `isFinalState` and `isStartingState` to `Node`. So I want `State` objects to be added to the `DFA` not the `Node` objects through `Graph`'s `addNode()` method.

I thought I can override and make this method `private` in `DFA` and have defined a new method `addState()` which will accept `State` objects. But reducing the visibility of parent class members in derived class is not allowed in Java.

So what is the standard solution / approach followed in such scenarios. Or am I thinking this all wrong?

Comment: "I thought I can override and make this method private in DFA". In Java, the access level cannot be more restrictive than the overridden method's access level. What this means is that you can't override a public method and change its access specifier to private.

Comment: yep I know that, the point is how should I go with the situation. I hope my requirement is genuine and am not messing up with the OO basics.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to comment on anything at the moment since your question is not clear. Put down the skeleton for each class that you plan to create and some basic methods you plan to add to them into the quesiton to make it more clear.

Comment: I don't think you're thinking about it wrong, but I would probably not model `State` unless its existence was fundamental to the problem being solved. At some point, we split frog hairs with unnecessary specialization and accomplish very little. I would put `isStartingState` and `isFinalState` on `Node` and call it a fine day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your example correctly, you can achieve that by Generics:

```
class Graph<T extends Node> {
    public void addNode(T node) { ... }
}

class DFA extends Graph<State> {
    @Override
    public void addNode(State node) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps `class Graph<T extends Node>`

Answer (score 0):

If your `DFA` class extends `Graph`, then it must maintain `Graph`'s contract. So, if you need to reduce the visibility of the method (not possible in Java as you say), you need to break the `Graph`'s contract for `DFA`and thus, `DFA` should not be a child of `Graph`.

Another way to say it is that as `DFA` cannot have `Node`s, then `DFA` is not a `Graph`.

Your solution could be that `DFA` doesn't extend `Graph` anymore (maybe you need a `IDFA` inteface?). In this case, your `DFA` class can keep a `Graph` as a field.

Also, thinking about what a Deterministic Finite Automaton is, it is not a graph, it's a state machine that can be represented using a graph.

Comment: Now thats interesting: *DFA is not a graph, it has a graph*

Comment: Edited: DFA is not a graph, it's a state machine that can be represented using a graph. I'm not a computer scientist, but I think it's correct

Comment: Ok thats correct sure 100%. DFA is a concept that can be represented by graph. And can also be represented by transitions tables. But I dont know if **represented by `Graph`** can also be termed as **contain `Graph`**